# Prove the following equation(much needed help):

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

Let there be a given function $f \in C([0,1])$, $f(x)>0$; $x\in [0,1]$. Prove

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{f\left({1\over n}\right)f\left({2\over n}\right)\cdots f\left({n\over n}\right)}=e^{\int_0^1 \log f(x) \, dx} $$

All the questions before this required solving an definite integral without Newton Leibnitz formula, then this came up, can anyone provide help?

Comment: Take logarithms (legit since $f>0$) and switch to Riemann sums.

Comment: Sorry to intrude but could you maybe type out  in general without too much detail? I would be very much apreciate it because im on a timeline. I also use this opportunity to give you great recognition for the three queens problem, the top ranked mathematician at the university agreed it was very impressive.

Comment: I am sorry for being late, but Chappers and kobe just give you plenty of details, I think my intervention is not needed anymore. Anyway, I am proud you and others liked my solution to the three queens problem :)

Comment: Thank you for the help. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is positive, and the logarithm is continuous on $(0,\infty)$, so we can take logarithms of both sides and swap the limit and logarithm to find
$$ \log{\left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{ f(1/n) f(2/n) \dotsm f(n/n) }\right)} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \log{\sqrt[n]{f(1/n)f(2/n)\dotsm f(n/n)}} $$
Now applying properties of the logarithm, the expression inside the limit on the right hand side is equal to
$$ \frac{1}{n}\log{\left( f(1/n)f(2/n)\dotsm f(n/n) \right)} = \frac{1}{n} \left( \log{f(1/n)}+\log{f(2/n)}+\dotsb+\log{f(n/n)} \right) \\
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n}\log{f(k/n)}, $$
which is a Riemann sum for $\log{f}$ on the interval $[0,1]$. Because $f$ is continuous, it is Riemann-integrable, and hence this sum must converge to the integral
$$ \int_0^1 \log{f(x)} \, dx, $$
which is the logarithm of the right-hand side of your original expression.

Comment: do you have time for a quick question>?

Comment: @BozoVulicevic You can ask, but I may not be able to answer immediately.

Comment: I figured it out , maybe next time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your limit is the same as

$$\exp\{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\left(\log f(1/n) +\log f(2/n) + \cdots + \log f(n/n)\right)\}$$

and the limit inside converges to $\int_0^1 \log f(x)\, dx$, since the sum inside is a sequence of Riemann sums of the continuous function $\log f(x)$ over $[0,1]$.