# Find the limit of function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I do not know how to approach this problem. Is there something related to integrating?

> The function $f$ is defined on $[0,1]$, continuous, and positive. Find the following limit:
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{f \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \cdot f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdot f\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdots f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)}$$

Comment: It is $e^{\int_0^{1}f(x)dx}$ Can you prove  it?

Comment: If only that pesky multiplication and exponentiation would somehow turn into nicer operations like addition and multiplication...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the following equation(much needed help):](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210285/prove-the-following-equationmuch-needed-help) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bn%5Cto%20%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Csqrt%5Bn%5D%7Bf%20%5Cleft(%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%7D%20%5Cright)%20%5Ccdot%20f%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright)%5Ccdot%20f%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright)%5Ccdots%20f%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7Bn%7D%7Bn%7D%5Cright)%7D%24)

Comment: @MartinR This Approach0 engine seems really handy, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Take log on both sides, 
Let $L_n= \sqrt[n]{f \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \cdot f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdot f\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdots f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)}\implies \ln L_n=\frac {\sum_{r=1}^n\ln f(\frac rn)}{n}$, which corresponds to Riemann sum for the integral $\int_0^1 \ln f(x) dx$.

$\lim(\ln L_n)=\int_0^1 \ln f(x) dx\implies L_n\to \exp (\int_0^1 \ln f(x) dx)$

In this case, you may convert to Riemann sum like this also: Replace $1/n$ by $dx$, put $r/n =x$. When $r=1, x=1/n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ (This gives lower limit for the above integral) and when $r=n, x=n/n\to 1 $ as $n\to \infty$ (for the upper limit).

Comment: This has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @MartinR: Ok. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2):

You have a product and powers. These are nasty; we like sums, sums are nice.
So take the logarithm to convert products into sums:
$$
\log \sqrt[n]{f \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \cdot f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdot f\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdots f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)}
= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \log f\!\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) \tag{1}
$$
Now, this looks like a Riemann sum, applied to the continuous, well-defined *(can you see why?)* function $g = \log \circ f$. In particular,

$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n g\!\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) = 
\int_0^1 g(x)dx \tag{2}
$$
Now, since $\exp$ is continuous, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} e^{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n g\!\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}
= e^{\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n g\!\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}
= e^{\int_0^1 g(x)dx} \tag{3}
$$
i.e., your limit is
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{f \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \cdot f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdot f\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdots f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)} 
= \boxed{e^{\int_0^1 \log(f(x))dx}}
$$

---

**Sanity check:** let's verify on a couple examples!

- $f$ is constant: if $f(x)=a>0$ for all $x$, then the limit is easily shown to be $\sqrt[n]{a^n}=a$, and $e^{\int_0^1 \log(a) dx} = e^{\log a} = a$. This checks out.
- $f(x)=x+1$ (this is continuous, positive, etc.). Then
  $$
  \sqrt[n]{f \left( \frac{1}{n} \right) \cdot f\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdot f\left(\frac{3}{n}\right)\cdots f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)} 
  = \sqrt[n]{ \frac{n+1}{n}\cdot\frac{n+2}{n}\cdots \frac{2n}{n} }
  = \sqrt[n]{ \frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n^n} }
  $$
  and,, e.g., using Sterling's inequality, you can check the limit is $4e^{-1}$.

On the other hand,
$e^{\int_0^1 \log(x+1) dx} = e^{\log 4-1} = 4e^{-1}$. This  again checks out.

Comment: This has been asked and answered before.

Comment: @MartinR I didn't know, and didn't find it. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @MartinR I do believe there is some extra value in my answer, though -- basically, very few answers on this website, and in particularly not the one you linked, provide the "sanity check" part, which IMO is a very useful and quite necessary step.